# Is it better to specify a public DNS on each host or send it through the gateway?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

In general do you get better performance if each host has a public DNS specified (like Google's 8.8.8.8) or is it better to just add that DNS to the gateway and then serve a DNS and point all hosts to it (perhaps adding the public DNS after the gateway for redundancy)? Does using the public DNS slow down page loading on hosts?

Answer (score 2):

> I've confirmed that it's better to include a public DNS server on each host for redundancy

No. It is better to have redundant nameservers but that has nothing to do with whether the nameserver is internal or public.

Also, your mention of adding a name server to "the gateway" leads me to believe that it is the sole route to the internet. Thus if it goes down public nameservers will be unreachable so no redundancy is gained.

You should have two internal, caching, and recursing name servers. This will provide redundancy and a marked performance improvement.

Answer (score -1):

After researching, I've confirmed that it's better to include a public DNS server on each host for redundancy. However, if your network is sizable you can also setup local DNS servers to sync with a remote DNS and serve this to clients on your network. Depending on your topology this could result in better performance for your users.